# Get last value of a continuous repeated property in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, grouping

I have this array of *transactions*:

```
const transactions = [
  {
    service: 'Some Text Assignment #1',
    phase: 'Assignment'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Processing #1',
    phase: 'Processing'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Processing #2',
    phase: 'Processing'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Issue Constancy #1',
    phase: 'Issue Constancy'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Quality Control #1',
    phase: 'Quality Control'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Signature and stamp #1',
    phase: 'Signature and stamp'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Signature and stamp #2',
    phase: 'Signature and stamp'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Signature and stamp #3',
    phase: 'Signature and stamp'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Processing #3',
    phase: 'Processing'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Processing #4',
    phase: 'Processing'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Signature and stamp #4',
    phase: 'Signature and stamp'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Signature and stamp #5',
    phase: 'Signature and stamp'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Approved #1',
    phase: 'Approved'
  }
];
```

I need to get the values grouped by the `phase`, but with a certain condition:

need the **last value** from **the phases that are continuous** within the **same phase value**.

What I want to get is something like this:

```
[
  {
    service: 'Some Text Assignment #1',
    phase: 'Assignment'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Processing #2',
    phase: 'Processing'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Issue Constancy #1',
    phase: 'Issue Constancy'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Quality Control #1',
    phase: 'Quality Control'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Signature and stamp #3',
    phase: 'Signature and stamp'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Processing #4',
    phase: 'Processing'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Signature and stamp #5',
    phase: 'Signature and stamp'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Approved #1',
    phase: 'Approved'
  }
]
```

I have tried is:

```
transactions.reduce((acc, value) => {
  acc[value.phase] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

But what I get is the last value of each `phase`. I have thinked in using `Maps` or `Sets`. Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other word: You just want to filter out duplicate phases:

```
  const result =  [...transactions]
    .reverse()
    .filter((el, i, arr) => !i || el.phase !== arr[i - 1].phase)
    .reverse();
```

Comment: Very simple and logical !

Answer (score 2):

You could add an item to the output if the next item in the array doesn't have the same `phase` as the current item

```js
const transactions=[{service:"Some Text Assignment #1",phase:"Assignment"},{service:"Some Text Processing #1",phase:"Processing"},{service:"Some Text Processing #2",phase:"Processing"},{service:"Some Text Issue Constancy #1",phase:"Issue Constancy"},{service:"Some Text Quality Control #1",phase:"Quality Control"},{service:"Some Text Signature and stamp #1",phase:"Signature and stamp"},{service:"Some Text Signature and stamp #2",phase:"Signature and stamp"},{service:"Some Text Signature and stamp #3",phase:"Signature and stamp"},{service:"Some Text Processing #3",phase:"Processing"},{service:"Some Text Processing #4",phase:"Processing"},{service:"Some Text Signature and stamp #4",phase:"Signature and stamp"},{service:"Some Text Signature and stamp #5",phase:"Signature and stamp"},{service:"Some Text Approved #1",phase:"Approved"}];

const output = []

transactions.forEach((o, i) => {
  const next = transactions[i + 1] || {};
  if (next.phase !== o.phase)
    output.push(o)
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Group adjacent items with `Array.reduce()`, then map and take the last item in each group:

```js
const transactions = [{"service":"Some Text Assignment #1","phase":"Assignment"},{"service":"Some Text Processing #1","phase":"Processing"},{"service":"Some Text Processing #2","phase":"Processing"},{"service":"Some Text Issue Constancy #1","phase":"Issue Constancy"},{"service":"Some Text Quality Control #1","phase":"Quality Control"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #1","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #2","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #3","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Processing #3","phase":"Processing"},{"service":"Some Text Processing #4","phase":"Processing"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #4","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #5","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Approved #1","phase":"Approved"}]

const result =
  transactions.reduce((r, o, i, arr) => {
    if(!i || o.phase !== arr[i - 1].phase) r.push([]);
    
    r[r.length - 1].push(o);
  
    return r;
  }, [])
  .map(arr => arr[arr.length - 1]);
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as following

- Maintain a variable that stores last visited phase
- For each element check whether the phase is same as value stored in phase variable
- If the value is different or undefined (for first value), push the value in array and set the value of phase in variable phase
- else update the last value in resultant array with item

```js
const transactions = [{"service":"Some Text Assignment #1","phase":"Assignment"},{"service":"Some Text Processing #1","phase":"Processing"},{"service":"Some Text Processing #2","phase":"Processing"},{"service":"Some Text Issue Constancy #1","phase":"Issue Constancy"},{"service":"Some Text Quality Control #1","phase":"Quality Control"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #1","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #2","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #3","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Processing #3","phase":"Processing"},{"service":"Some Text Processing #4","phase":"Processing"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #4","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #5","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Approved #1","phase":"Approved"}];

let phase;
const result = transactions.reduce((a,c) => {
  if(phase && c.phase == phase) a[a.length-1] = c;
  else { a.push(c); phase = c.phase;}
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempted solution is almost correct, but you should check the last inserted object rather than any inserted object.

```js
const transactions = [
  {
    service: 'Some Text Assignment #1',
    phase: 'Assignment'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Processing #1',
    phase: 'Processing'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Processing #2',
    phase: 'Processing'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Issue Constancy #1',
    phase: 'Issue Constancy'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Quality Control #1',
    phase: 'Quality Control'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Signature and stamp #1',
    phase: 'Signature and stamp'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Signature and stamp #2',
    phase: 'Signature and stamp'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Signature and stamp #3',
    phase: 'Signature and stamp'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Processing #3',
    phase: 'Processing'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Processing #4',
    phase: 'Processing'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Signature and stamp #4',
    phase: 'Signature and stamp'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Signature and stamp #5',
    phase: 'Signature and stamp'
  },
  {
    service: 'Some Text Approved #1',
    phase: 'Approved'
  }
];

let out = transactions.reduce((acc, value) => {
  let last = acc.length && acc[acc.length - 1];
  if (last && last.phase === value.phase)
    last.service = value.service;
  else
    acc.push(value);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check adjacent values and add once you see non matching phases

```js
const transactions = [{"service":"Some Text Assignment #1","phase":"Assignment"},{"service":"Some Text Processing #1","phase":"Processing"},{"service":"Some Text Processing #2","phase":"Processing"},{"service":"Some Text Issue Constancy #1","phase":"Issue Constancy"},{"service":"Some Text Quality Control #1","phase":"Quality Control"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #1","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #2","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #3","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Processing #3","phase":"Processing"},{"service":"Some Text Processing #4","phase":"Processing"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #4","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Signature and stamp #5","phase":"Signature and stamp"},{"service":"Some Text Approved #1","phase":"Approved"}]


let final = transactions.reduce((op,inp,index)=>{
  if( index + 1 ===  transactions.length){
    if(transactions[index-1].phase !== inp.phase){
      op.push(inp)
    }
  }
  else if(transactions[index+1].phase !== inp.phase){
    op.push(inp)
  }
  return op
},[])

console.log(final)
```